# Spectrum of triangular pulse - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I am new in matlab.I was given the code for spectrum of rectangular pulse of amplitude 1V and duration 1ms, and now I have to find the spectrum of a triangular pulse of amplitude 1V and duration 1ms in MATLAB using FFT. How would that code look like?

```
~~~
fs=10000; 
step=1/fs;
N=5000;
t=0:step:(N*step);
z(1:10)=1; % amplitude 1V
z(11:N)=0; 
Z=fft(z);
number=round((N+1)/2);
plot((0:(number-1))*fs/N,1/fs*abs(Z(1:number))); 
mag=abs(Z).^2;
E2=(1/(N*fs))*sum(mag)
~~~
```

Comment: Requests for working code are specifically off-topic on this forum. Worse, this question shows _no_ effort at trying to find the answer. I vote to close.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you rectangular pulse is in the first 10 indices of z, so the triangular pulse should go in the same location.  I am assuming that it is the peak voltage you have specified as a triangular pulse doesn't have a constant envelope. I am also assuming the pulse goes from 0 to 1 V and then back to 0.

Replace

```
z(1:10)=1; % amplitude 1V
```

with

```
% triangular wave, peak of 1V
z(1:5) = linspace(0, 1, 5);
z(6:9) = z(4:-1:1);
```

Note that this doesn't extend over 10 samples as there is some ambiguity as to the desired waveform pulse definition and for an even number of samples its not going to be able to go from min value to max value and back to min value with a single sample at the peak.